# Display PostScript in WPF

Tags: wpf, postscript

I'd like to display some sheet music in my WPF application which was generated by Lilypond.  Lilypond can make postscript and PNG files - I've got the latter working, but I'd much prefer the former so that the music can be resized nicely.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please share with the community if you find a solution for this. I've long wondered if it would be possible to modify Lilypond itself to output Xaml rather than postscript.

Comment: I'll keep you posted Simon.  Unfortunately I haven't found much yet.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest, but perhaps distasteful to many, would be to shell-out and use an external program render the postscript to png. You'd probably want to display some generic "working, please wait" message, as making an accurate progress-bar would be quite a chore.

Alternately, ghostscript can be used as a library and can read the PS from memory and render to memory, potentially saving some disk-access.